# Нужно сделать функцию, превращающую обычные цифры в укороченную запись с "k" вместо нулей. javascript

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять как это сделать функцию. Например чтобы она работала так -

```
order(10100) //"10.1k"
order(1217114) //"1.2kk"
order(10765454) //"10.7kk"
```

Получилось сделать что-то подобное, но с расстановкой точек - `dots(10100)` возвращает - 10.100

```
function dots(string) {
    if(typeof string !== "string") string = string.toString();
    return string.split("").reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(".").split("").reverse().join("");
};
```

Прошу помощи :)

Comment: По поводу "сокращений" по типу "1к", есть где-то инфа о том, какие ещё есть буквы у разных величин?

Comment: Мне не нужны другие символы. Вот примеры работы функции: 1000101 = 1кк; 2010 = 2к; 1459834 = 1.4kk;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для обрезки дробной части есть специальная функция [`Number.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), остальное достигается делением в цикле:

```js
console.log(order(4954373572))
console.log(order(418998628))
console.log(order(1158897094))

function order(n) {
  for (var k = ''; n>1e3; n /= 1e3, k += 'k');
  return Math.floor(n*10)/10 + k;
}
```

Comment: Да, вроде все отлично, но с большими числами работает не так как нужно. Мне нужно чтобы миллионы и тд обозначались как "кк", "ккк" и тд.

1000101 = 1кк
2010 = 2к
1459834 = 1.4kk

Comment: @kusb подправил

Comment: Спасибо большое. Можете еще сказать как сделать так, чтобы order(501034) не возвращал 501.0k
Ну то есть когда 0 - он не возвращается

Comment: @kusb а это надо дополнительно обработать, мин

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Помогли очень

Comment: @kusb пожалуйста, потестируйте ее получше на границе условия в toFixed

Comment: Я сейчас проверил все это циклом, и да, ошибки есть:
7113185082 - 7.1kkk;
975648260 - 975.6kk;
329143360 - 329.1kk;
4631151974 - 4.6kkk;
8410060163 - 8.4kkk;
6210086572 - 6.2kkk;
4066180016 - 4.1kkk;
9170876956 - 9.2kkk;
5546761075 - 5.5kkk;
3472509143 - 3.5kkk;
8621648733 - 8.6kkk;
1158897094 - 1.2kkk;
9322001032 - 9.3kkk;
3837493759 - 3.8kkk;
3902248678 - 3.9kkk;
8602954131 - 8.6kkk;
90916839 - 90.9kk;
3706400431 - 3.7kkk;
7606972240 - 7.6kkk;
8937943650 - 8.9kkk;
2856699269 - 2.9kkk;
4698369837 - 4.7kkk;
7919222306 - 7.9kkk;
4954373572 - 5.0kkk;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96461/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-kusb).

Comment: Выше скинул часть цикла. Иногда все также возвращает 0, а иногда возвращает число больше чем оно есть. То есть округляет в большую сторону